# How can I export .melt into Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

I've used the melt function and it is exactly what I am after and working perfectly. However, how can I take this view and export it into Excel?

Even when I call the df after using the melt function, it reverts back into the 'un'melted df (long to wide)

```
all_recons.melt(id_vars=["Client Name", "Client Code"], 
        var_name="Date", 
        value_name="Cost to Client")

Client Code      Date           Cost
237762          01/01/2024  98.91438
237762          01/01/2024  108.1454
101145          01/01/2024  113884.02025
101145          01/02/2024  1525.90438
101145          01/02/2024  4427.17275
```

Then why I try and call my df again it reverts back to the long to wide format

```
all_recons

Client Code     01/01/2024      01/02/2024
237762          98.91438        NaN
237762          108.1454        NaN
101145          113884.02025    NaN
101145          Nan             1525.90438
101145          NaN             4427.17275
```

I'd like it so that the df stays in the melted state and then I can export to Excel

Comment: `all_recons = all_recons.melt(...)`.

Comment: Like BigBen is saying, you need to save the object `.melt` returns before exporting to excel.

Comment: Ah of course, than you!